# Cannot set to undefined value in ID

Tags: javascript

Hello for some reason is always giving me error when i try add the values in my foor loop, here is my funciton:

```
var productIds = [1,2,3,4,5];

var products = {};  
for (i = 0; i < productIds.length; ++i) {

    products[i]['id'] = id;
}
```

My error is:

```
ht TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined.
```

Comment: You have to initialize `products[i]` with an object value first. The object doesn't magically come into existence.

Comment: Add `products[i] = {}` before `products[i]['id'] = id;`

Comment: Or just do `products[i] = {id};` or `products[i] = {id: id}` (whatever `id` is here).

Comment: @FelixKling i think not everrybody fomes from js background, since i work most of the time in php, and in php it does magically com into existence...

Comment: @MarcoPereira that might be fair, but if you're using another language, it would be useful to study how things work in that new language.

Comment: If you actually want to use the values in `productIds` I'd suggest a different approach and use `.map`: `var products = productIds.map(id => ({id}))`. I guess you actually want an array of products, not an object of products that looks like an array. Also I'd say that PHP is the exception here rather than the norm :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code by this approach-

```js
var productIds = [1,2,3,4,5];

var products = {};  
for (i = 0; i < productIds.length; ++i) {
  products[i] = {};
  products[i]['id'] = productIds[i];
}

console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the `products[i]` to a new object inside the `for` loop first like:

```
products[i] = {};
products[i]['id'] = id;
```

Or, add the object inline like:

```
products[i]= { 'id': id };
```

Or, simply use Object property shorthand like:

```
products[i]= { id };
```

DEMO:

```js
var productIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var products = {}, id = 2;
for (i = 0; i < productIds.length; ++i) {
  products[i] = {id};
}
console.log(products);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var productIds = [1,2,3,4,5];

var products = {};  

productIds.forEach(item => {
 var id_available = item in products
 if (!id_available) {
  products[item] = {id : item}
 } else {
  products[item].id = item
 }
})
console.log(products)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var productIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
 var products = {};  
 for (i = 0; i < productIds.length; ++i) {
    products[i]={"id":productIds[i]};
 }
```

It should be work for you.

Note : products parameter data work as Object Data.